# Webrtc rendering video screenshot

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I want to take screenshot of rendered remotevideo view.

So far I tried these functions:

1.

```
public Bitmap getLastFrame(RelativeLayout remoteView)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if(remoteView.getChildCount()>0) {
            SurfaceViewRenderer rtcEAGLView = (SurfaceViewRenderer) remoteView.getChildAt(0);
            rtcEAGLView.getBackground();
              bitmap = ActivityUtils.takeScreenshot(rtcEAGLView);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(View container) {
        container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getScreenShot(container);

        final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(container.getWidth(), container.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        container.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        container.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        container.layout(0, 0, container.getMeasuredWidth(), container.getMeasuredHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(container.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, new Paint());

        return bmp;
    }
```

2. ```
   void frame()
   {
       EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
       GL10 gl = (GL10)egl.eglGetCurrentContext().getGL();
       Bitmap snapshotBitmap = createBitmapFromGLSurface(0, 0, 400, 400/* height*/, gl);
   }
   ```

By trying these method I am not able to get screenshot as bitmap returns blank space only. rest of the area screenshot get captured but rendered part is not deplayed in that.